# Who established space as a pause button?

Tags: menu, guidelines, intuition

Title is pretty much self-explanatory, which application did establish space as a pause button  in media players in general?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find the source of who proposed the idea of using Space to Pause and Resume a video. Unfortunately, I could not find an exact source.

That being said, it has a reason to be there. When watching a video the focus of attention of the user is entirely on the video itself. It makes sense to place the largest key in the keyboard to perform the function of Pausing a video. This allows the user to either resume its activities or take another path in its interaction.

I recall seeing the Spacebar as a Pausing/Resuming function within a video in Windows Media Player in Windows 98. I might be wrong, I would need to check in an old computer. It was probably popularized by Flash videos on the web, specially YouTube which has an enormous reach across the world.